# Android Scanner Does not Focus On Textbox in Chrome after the Screen is unlocked

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome

I have a web app that is just used for scanning. It is important that the input box is always in focus.
I am using this bit of code to ensure that a certain textbox always has focus in the page.

```
function setFocus() {
    document.getElementById('SerTextBox').focus();
}
var t = setInterval(setFocus, 1000);
```

When I unlocked the phone, I noticed that I could not scan to that textbox immediately, but had to tap on the textbox first. The textbox even had a flashing cursor indicating that the specific textbox was in focus.

I have tried this, and I would think it should work. It does not.

```
function onWindowOpened() {
    document.getElementById('SerTextBox').focus();
}
window.addEventListener("focus", onWindowOpened);
```

I need a solution to keep the textbox in focus when the user unlocks their device.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this was to add a line to lose focus and then reestablish it.

`document.getElementById('SerTextBox').blur();`

Here is the final bit of code.

```
function onWindowOpened() {
    document.getElementById('SerTextBox').blur();
    document.getElementById('SerTextBox').focus();
}
window.addEventListener("focus", onWindowOpened);
```

It seems to be working correctly now.